# Snapped rear light assembly case

Tags: honda, lights, crv, rear-end

I foolishly reversed (very slowly) into something that wasn’t nice and soft. As a result, my near side rear light got pushed back “into” the car and the cover broke.

I have a new rear light assembly to replace this, but when I went to remove the old one, the snap-in base was still...snapped in. Any advice on how I can get it out so I can snap the new rear light in place?[image]

Answer (score 1):

There exists plastic levers to, well, lever those things out
[image]